# Ordering transactions in a batch multisend/multicall

Tags: uniswap, gnosis-safe, multisignature, batch

I've learned you can batch multiple transactions into one transaction using contracts like multisend/multicall. This is useful for things like large airdrops.

However, what if we need to order the transactions?
Eg. Trx 1 - approve contractA to use my tokens.
Trx 2 - let contractA do use my tokens.

The above needs to ordered.. but Im not sure how this is done if both calls are merged into one transaction in one block?

Any idea how this will work? Is it random? Or if we put the calldata for trx1 first, before trx2, would it work somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [Gnosis-Safe's MultiSend contract](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/libraries/MultiSend.sol), you'll notice that you decide in which order you want to execute the "sub"-transaction.

You need to encode each transaction you want to batch like this.

For an `approve(...)`:

- (1) **operation (1 bytes)**: either `0x00` (for a call) or `0x01` (for a delegate call)
- (2) **to (20 bytes)**: the target address of the transaction (e.g: `0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f`)
- (3) **data_length (32 bytes)**: the length of the next field `data` (e.g: if the length of `data` is 68 bytes, that would be `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044`)
- (4) **data (<data_length> bytes)**: the bytes code to execute the function against the contract `to` (e.g: for an approve call, that would be `0x095ea7b300000000000000000000000068b34cc833fb72a70ecdfaa5e0e4c7bd86bbfc45ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`)

Which mean your first encoded sub-transaction will look like this

```
0x00dafea492d9c6733ae3d56b7ed1adb60692c98bc5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003A0x095ea7b300000000000000000000000068b34cc833fb72a70ecdfaa5e0e4c7bd86bbfc45ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Repeat this step for the next sub-transaction you want to include.

For a `transfer(...)`:

- (1) **operation (1 bytes)**: either `0x00` (for a call) or `0x01` (for a delegate call)
- (2) **to (20 bytes)**: the target address of the transaction (e.g: `0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f`)
- (3) **data_length (32 bytes)**: the length of the next field `data` (e.g: if the length of `data` is 68 bytes, that would be `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044`)
- (4) **data (<data_length> bytes)**: the bytes code to execute the function against the contract `to` (e.g: for an approve call, that would be `0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000823e309b1a730f8aa6b0ae7f9165abbf8b1950ae00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003635c9ad45dea00000`)

Which gives you an encoded version equals to

```
0x006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044
a9059cbb000000000000000000000000823e309b1a730f8aa6b0ae7f9165abbf8b1950ae00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003635c9ad45dea00000
```

If you want to batch both together, simply concatenate it (in one line):

```
0x
00dafea492d9c6733ae3d56b7ed1adb60692c98bc5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003A0x095ea7b300000000000000000000000068b34cc833fb72a70ecdfaa5e0e4c7bd86bbfc45ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044a9059cbb000000000000000000000000823e309b1a730f8aa6b0ae7f9165abbf8b1950ae00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003635c9ad45dea00000
```

Finally, this is the argument `bytes transactions` you need pass to the function `multiSend` to execute multiple transactions in one.

[image]

**The order will be the same as the logic above**

Comment: Amazing, will try that out. TY Greg