# are there other ways to send bundle of transactions without using flashbot?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, ethereumjs

I am wondering if there are some ways to send bundle of transactions without using flashbot?

I am not sure how this area works,

would you please give me practical sources to learn ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ordering transactions in a batch multisend/multicall](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/136945/ordering-transactions-in-a-batch-multisend-multicall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bundle transactions using a `Multi Call` contract. Just encode all your transactions into one and use the `Multi Call` contract. Here is the [link](https://solidity-by-example.org/app/multi-call/)

Comment: This `MultiCall` contract is for viewing data from multiple contracts and not for interacting with contracts in a stateful manner.